# Pull the content out of a page

Tags: php, cms

I wanna pull the data from this area "see the red area on the image below"

[image]

Out to a specific template

I have a page template named page.php

```
<div class="contentholder">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
            <?php comments_template( '', false ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
        <br />
    </div>
```

but this just send me a comment field.. i need the text in the page

and i need the header

Comment: There is a call to get_template_part, can you post the relevant code for content.php or content-page.php? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While inside a query loop, this function will output the current posts title:

```
the_title();
```

This function will output the content:

```
the_content();
```

What I suspect has happened however is that you are instead calling `get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );` and expecting it to output the content for the page, when what it's actually doing is checking if there's a `content-page.php`, and including it if it's present, if not it checks for `content.php` and includes that, and because neither exist, it's doing nothing, and so you get no content.

For more details on what `get_template_part` actually does, look here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

**EDIT***
Working snippet:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php the_title(); ?>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the surrounding code im pretty new at wordpress so if you could make a snippet that i could just take to post it, it would be nice

Comment: You mean a copy paste? I'm sorry but that's not what you asked for. The 2 calls above are already in a highly copy pastable form, put the bit that displays the title in the part where you want it to display the title, and put the bit that displays the content in the bit where you display the content. I shan't demean myself with copypasta

Comment: nvm i got it now